# Find a bone by name

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

Is there a way to search for the name of a bone within an armature and find where it is? Many complex armatures have tons of layers. When attempting to modify them or their constraints, it can be very difficult to locate a specific bone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a search box in outliner window view, does that help.

[image: 1]

Comment: I know you might know this already, but any specific requirement? I am trying to make an extension which helps me in this and few other stuff, dealing with shortcuts and selections.

Comment: Sorry, I had no armature, but would do that for you :)  ... edited as suggested